# Can I infer correlation from two time series

Tags: correlation

Consider the following plot of two variables unemployment and underemployment in different years in the US.

Can I infer a positive correlation between unemployment and underemployment? For this purpose, I have usually seen scatter plots are used, but it seems that this plot also shows the correlation, right?
[image]

Comment: With a little practice you can learn to estimate the correlation coefficient accurately from a scatterplot.  That's not possible with this pair of time series plots: typically, you should feel lucky to determine the sign of the correlation accurately from such plots.

Comment: @whuber but they decrease and increase together, doesn't it mean a positive correlation? I'm not sure, what's the problem here.

Comment: Yes--but can you reliably tell us what the correlation coefficient is from this plot?  You could readily determine that from the scatterplot.

Answer (score 0):

Before assessing your main question, we need to clarify some points:

1) inference is not the same thing of computing or showing the correlation;

2) since you are working with time series, you need to check if the series are both stationary or cointegrated; if it is not the case, you're correlation may be spurious and your conclusion, fallacious;

3) quantitative measures are in the vast majority of cases preferred to graphical methods; in the case of correlation, you should compute an appropriate coefficient rather than giving your conclusion using only a plot. After you have computed the coefficient, you should test if it is statistically significant.